# Sequelize Express Example - why is fs.readdirSync not repeatedly called?

Tags: node.js

## EDIT (I think I solved it)

It's the Node require cache!  So the first time it requires `models/index.js` it actually runs the file and hits the call to readdirSync which gets executed.

Then the next time we require `models/index.js` it just pulls it from the cache - no need to hit the disk again confirming why it isn't a complete inefficiency.

============

This relates to the Express Example provided by the Sequelize ORM project.  The GitHub repo is https://github.com/sequelize/express-example

## The question

I am confused why `fs.readdirSync` isn't called each time the `models/index.js` file is required.  Can anybody explain why?

## The code in question...

### Models

Starting with the `models` directory you will find an `index.js` which bootstraps the models and has a call to `fs.readdirSync` which reads the rest of the models within that directory and loads them (more accurately calls `sequelize.import`).

I added a console log to the file.

```
fs
  .readdirSync(__dirname)
  .filter(function(file) {
    return (file.indexOf(".") !== 0) && (file !== "index.js");
  })
  .forEach(function(file) {
    var model = sequelize.import(path.join(__dirname, file));
    db[model.name] = model;
    console.log('#########  INSIDE FS #########');
  });
```

There are 2 other models defined, namely `task.js` and `user.js` which defines the Schema and sets some relationships.

### Routes

Next, the `routes` directory you will find two files.

The `index.js` file defines the index route (a single get to list users and their tasks).

The `users.js` file defines the users with some REST endpoints to create a new user or to create/delete tasks for a user.

Both of the routes start with `var models  = require('../models');`

## The app.js File

Inside the `app.js` file the routes are both included and used.

## Repeat of the question with more detail

When I run `npm start` and it loads the app I see the console.log from the readdirSync shown in the console twice.

But if the 2 routes both required `models/index.js` which has a call to `fs.readdirSync` which loads 2 files why does fs.readdirSync not get called 4 times?    (Or if I had more routes including model/index.js that many multiplied by the number of models)

Or asked another way - why are the console logs ONLY shown when the app starts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more of a node.js question,

In node.js after initial load the module gets cached so when you first hit require it will get cached and will not execute all the functions again sequentially

Refer to questions on how node require works or ref like this http://fredkschott.com/post/2014/06/require-and-the-module-system/